# Mavericks Mail Applescript Changes

Tags: email, applescript, osx-mavericks

Mavericks has been pretty good so far, but one truststy Applescript I'd been using for years decided it didn't wan to work anymore. The script is here:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set the clipboard to (content of first message of ¬
        inbox whose subject contains "2013-11-05") as string
end tell
```

The job of the script is to get the content from an email with a subject "J-List Reports 2013-11-05") (obviously this changes each day). If I change the script to look for "J-List reports" with no date it works fine, but it gets the wrong email since I can't specify the date (it looks for the first message that happens to have this string in the subject). If any numbers are in the Applescript, trying to force it to find the correct email, I get

> "Mail got an error: can't get message 1 of inbox whose subject
>   contains 2013-11-05"

even though nothing else has changed.

Can anyone suggest a way to specify the correct mail, perhaps any mail whose subject contains "J-List reports" and whose month is 11 and whose day is 5? I spent a couple hours but couldn't get it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
tell application "Mail"
    content of message 1 of mailbox "[Gmail]/All Mail" of account "Gmail" where subject contains "2013-11-05"
end tell
set the clipboard to result
```

The messages are sorted from newest to oldest, so `message 1` should be the newest message.

`tell application "Mail" to messages of inbox` and `tell application "Mail" to messages of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Gmail"` returned an empty list for some reason.

Comment: Hi Lauri. I've been having the same problem with the empty list. This doesn't work either: tell application "Mail" to messages of sent mailbox

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me

```
tell application "Mail"
    try
        set the clipboard to (content of first message of ¬
            inbox whose subject contains "2013-11-05") as string
    on error errMsg
        display dialog "an error: " & errMsg
    end try
end tell
```

Try changing the string to something you know exists , I get the same error when I search for an email message where there are no matches. I suspect that you are not including the full error message here either

```
rror "Mail got an error: Can’t get message 1 of inbox whose subject contains \"2013-11-05\". Invalid index." number -1719
```

invalid index is important to a diagnosis because it tells us exactly what the problem is. There is no message that can be identified where the subject contains 2013-11-05

so you should use a try statement and then decided what to do from there.

Mail Version 7.0 (1816)
OS 10.9 build 13a603